# I want to choose specific characters from a variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I capture the text value and store it in a variable. Now I want to use the specific characters from the variable. How can I do it in Ruby?

```
var = "ABC-DEF-XYZ"
```

I want to use `"DEF"` value from the variable and want to skip the rest.

Comment: `"DEF"` based on what condition? If there is no condition and you already know the value what point extracting it?

Comment: You are supposed to show some effort. Invalid code can easily be avoided and posting it nonetheless results in (well-deserved) downvotes. Speaking of effort, what have you tried so far to extract the substring?

Comment: Have an input selection box which has values in format x-y-z and a table list that stores value y. how can i compare the value from input selection box to that of the table list value.

Comment: @BMR Please add your code and any clarifying information to your question.  You can click the 'edit' button to add more information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the 'y' value from your string using one of these 2 methods:

1. Regex

   ```
   y = input_value.gsub(/^\w\w\w-(\w\w\w)-\w\w\w$/, "\\1")
   ```
2. Split

   ```
   y = input_value.split('-')[1]
   ```

Once you have the 'y' value from your input, you can compare it to the table list.